# vuex store doesn't make requests to api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

i have this vuex store, each time i try to access my store , i dont see any data

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import myModule from './modules/myModule';
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    myModule,
  },
});
export default store;
```

this is my modules

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
  posts: []
};
const getters = {
  allPosts: state => state.posts
};
const actions = {
  async fetchPosts({ commit }) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      console.log(response)
      commit('setPosts', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
};
const mutations = {
  setPosts: (state, posts) => {
    state.posts = posts;
  }
};
export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

[image]

this is my main.js file to import my store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = true;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

but each time i check my vue dev tool to view my store i dont get any data

[image]

this is my package.json ,i'm using vue2

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
```

Comment: Can you show us the component calling you're fetchPosts action ?

Comment: @jibzy Can you put in your post the result of the console.log

Comment: "thank you"?  You didn't add the information that was asked.  First step to debug is to verify `fetchPosts` is being called properly.  If `fetchPosts` isn't called, then `posts` obviously won't populate.  Please post the code showing how you call your store action.